# Pandas aggregation: return only value in group, raise error if there are several

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate, data-wrangling

When wrangling dataframes, I often want to aggregate data while preserving some high-level variables. I don't want to group by these higher level variables, because this is not what I mean.

Is there an existing aggregation function that returns the unique value of a series (in each group), and throws an error if there are multiple different values?

### Example

Consider this table:

```py
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({"plant_id": [14] * 2 + [15, 16] * 3,
                  "plant": ["cactus"] * 2 + ["clover", "rose"] * 3,
                  "score": [1, 2, 6, 4, 7, 9, 2, 4],
                  "spikes": [False, True] + [False, True] * 3})
    .sort_values('plant_id')
)

#    plant_id   plant  score  spikes
# 0        14  cactus      1   False
# 1        14  cactus      2    True
# 2        15  clover      6   False
# 4        15  clover      7   False
# 6        15  clover      2   False
# 3        16    rose      4    True
# 5        16    rose      9    True
# 7        16    rose      4    True
```

I would like to get the average score of each plant, keeping both the `plant_id` and the `plant` name. One way to do it is to group by both variables.

```py
df.group_by(['plant_id', 'plant']).agg({'score': "mean"})
```

This could be fine in this simple example, this isn't exactly what I mean.
What I actually want is to group by `plant_id`, and then to keep the `plant`
name, knowing that there is always only one plant name per plant id.
Is there an existing function or method that would do something like
`unique_value` here?

```py
df.groupby('plant_id').agg({'plant': lambda x: unique_value(x),
                            'score': "mean"})

#            plant     score
# plant_id                  
# 14        cactus  1.500000
# 15        clover  5.000000
# 16          rose  5.666667
```

Ideally, this function would raise an error if I try to apply it to a series
that has several values:

```py
df.groupby('plant_id').agg({'plant': lambda x: unique_value(x),
                            'spikes': lambda x: unique_value(x),
                            'score': "mean"})

# ValueError: Not unique: some cactuses have spikes, and some don't!
```

Comment: how looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution with existing methods only: `x.unique().item()`.

"unique item" says what it does, and [`item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html?highlight=item) throws an error if applied to an object that is not of length 1.

```py
df.groupby('plant_id').agg({'plant': lambda x: x.unique().item(),
                            'score': "mean"})

#           plant     score
# plant_id      
# 14        cactus    1.500000
# 15        clover    5.000000
# 16        rose      5.666667
```

```py
df.groupby('plant_id').agg({'plant': lambda x: x.unique().item(),
                            'spikes': lambda x: x.unique().item(),
                            'score': "mean"})

# ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) with custom function for raise error if not unique values - length is greater like `1`:

```
def unique_value(x):
    u = x.unique()
    if len(u) > 1:
        raise ValueError('Non unique value per group')
    else:
        return u[0]

df = df.groupby('plant_id').agg({'plant': lambda x: unique_value(x),
                            'spikes': lambda x: unique_value(x),
                            'score': "mean"})
print (df)
```

> ValueError: Non unique value per group

---

```
def unique_value(x):
    u = x.unique()
    if len(u) > 1:
        raise ValueError('Non unique value per group')
    else:
        return u[0]

df = df.groupby('plant_id').agg({'plant': lambda x: unique_value(x),
                                 'score': "mean"})
print (df)
           plant     score
plant_id                  
14        cactus  1.500000
15          rose  5.666667
16        clover  5.000000
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do :)  
But it seems so common that I'm surprised that this doesn't exist in pandas yet

Comment: @rturquier - There was typo, not `len(x)` but `len(u)`